# How do I make a sshpass scp bash script for password and not keys to be run as a cron?

Tags: bash, scp, sshpass

I am trying to make a bash script to send a file. When running this in the terminal I get the error:

line 4: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p 'password' scp /dir/sub/sub/sub/sub/file.csv username@ftps.server.com:/ <<-EOF
quit
EOF
```

It will send the file but when I have tried to run the script with crontab it will not run. What do I need to change? Also I am only able to use a password and not keys.

Comment: Why do you have a here-document?  `scp` is not interactive, you don't have to send a `quit` command.

Comment: What would be a better solution for this script? I need something that would work.

Comment: Just get rid of everything from `<<-EOF` to `EOF`, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: I did that and it worked without errors, thanks for the answer. However, the cron set to run the script is still not sending the file.

Comment: Redirect stdout and stderr to a file, then check the file to see if it's getting an error.

Comment: Is the user `username` really allowed to write to `/` on ftps.server.com?

Comment: It is, when running the script in terminal it writes the file just fine, but not as a cron.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code to work:

#### cron job script: `cron-job--scp-files-locally.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# create an ind file with current minute timestamp
touch $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M).ind
# scp all ind files to /tmp with user metoo
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'greatPassword' /usr/bin/scp *.ind metoo@localhost:/tmp
# remove all ind files
rm -f *.ind
```

#### crontab line for current user is:

```
* * * * * /home/greatuser/cron-job--scp-files-locally.sh
```

#### Output test: `ls -1 /tmp/*ind`

```
/tmp/2023-12-11_1619.ind
/tmp/2023-12-11_1620.ind
/tmp/2023-12-11_1621.ind
```

### Summery

##### Suggested cron job script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'greatPassword' /usr/bin/scp /dir/sub/sub/sub/sub/file.csv username@ftps.server.com:/
```

Comment: Any password that has ever been passed in a command line should be considered compromised -- yes, `sshpass` tries to redact from the command line after it finishes starting up, but there's a window before it can do it where anything listing the process tree can read the password in plaintext. Much better to pass the password in the environment -- that way only processes running as the same user or as root can read it -- or via a file descriptor (`<(printf '%s\n' "$password")` gets filesystem-level security and has its contents consumed after being read only once)

Comment: Also, if targeting a modern bash release (this was a feature introduced somewhere around 4.3/4.4), think about `printf -v filename '%(%Y-%m-%D_%H%M)T.ind' -1 && >>"$filename"` instead of using `date` or `touch`; that way you don't pay the performance cost to start an external executable.